Bash code not counting identical lines properly
I need to get a count of how many unique blast hits I've obtained for my list of OTUs/ASVs but for some reason, in what appears to be random cases lines that are identical are not adding up properly. Other times however, the code works fine and is summing up identical lines no problem. I have already made sure to run dos2unix on my files, I'm running my command on Linux and I don't know what else to check for.
Here is a reproducible example:
Input file called check_text.csv with lines below:
ASV Genus_Species   Taxid
cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia solbrigii 460333
46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Marticorenia foliosa    1910960
46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Leucheria candidissima  1911693
46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia solbrigii 460333
46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Oxyphyllum ulicinum 540062

My code I run:
dos2unix check_text.csv
dos2unix: converting file check_text.csv to Unix format...

cat check_text.csv | uniq -c > hitcounts.csv

But here is the output I keep getting in my hitcounts.csv file:
  1 ASV Genus_Species   Taxid
  5 cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
  1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia solbrigii 460333
  1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Marticorenia foliosa    1910960
  1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Leucheria candidissima  1911693
  1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia solbrigii 460333
  1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Oxyphyllum ulicinum 540062

The first line is fine, those are just headers that is not a problem. But I should have seen the following:
  1 ASV Genus_Species   Taxid
  5 cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
  2 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia solbrigii 460333
  1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Marticorenia foliosa    1910960
  1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Leucheria candidissima  1911693
  1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Oxyphyllum ulicinum 540062

The line with Moscharia solbrigii is coming up twice as if these lines are not identical but they are. What could be the problem? I manually check some of these for extra white spaces but there aren't any.

sort file.csv | uniq -c ?

I can't sort it because I need it in the original list - there is a whole other part I have to do after to align it back to another file with the same ASV list.
While I did try sorting it though just to check on a subset it does seem to solve that issue but is there no way to make this work without sorting? I just need the ASV list in the same order as it appears.

awk '{ if (!seen[$0]++) order[++count] = $0 } END { for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) print seen[order[i]], order[i] }' file.csv maybe.

Oh that worked! Thanks so much!

What you have, using a pipe is not limited to bash it should work with any POSIX compliant shell. In pure bash that would need a loop and (associative) array. It would be very-very slow for large data/file size...

You don't need the second array. Just print not-yet-seen lines as you run across them.  The whole command can be just awk '!seen[$0]++'

@MarkReed: awk '!seen[$0]++' will uniqueify but not provide a count...

in comments you've stated need the ASV list in the same order as it appears; what does this mean when (in the sample) the Moscharia ... line shows up in two different places in the input but you only want it to show up in one place in the output? which of those 2 Moscharia ... lines should be considered as being in the same order as it appears?  follow-on question to think about ... what does it mean to align it back to another file when the Moscharia ... lines are non-adjacent?

Note the uniq man page:

'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.
You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without
'uniq'

You can use Ruby with CSV parser and generator:
ruby -r csv -e '
opts={:headers=>true, :col_sep=>"\t"}
puts CSV.generate(**opts){ |csv|  
        tbl=CSV.parse($<.read, **opts)
        tally=tbl.map{|row| row.to_a.map(&:last)}.tally
        csv<<["1"]+tbl.to_a[0]
        tally.each{|x,cnt| csv<<[cnt]+x }
        } 
' file.tsv

You can also use two awks and a sort:
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{print 1,$0; exit}' file.tsv

awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{next}
{cnt[$0]++}
END{for (e in cnt) print cnt[e],e}
' file.tsv | sort -k1,1rn  

Either prints:
# These are ordered by header then decreasing frequency
1   ASV Genus_Species   Taxid   
5   cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum    amygdalinum 82755
2   46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia   solbrigii   460333
1   46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Marticorenia    foliosa 1910960
1   46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Leucheria   candidissima    1911693
1   46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Oxyphyllum  ulicinum    540062   

Or, if you want to print them in the file order encountered rather than by value:
ruby -lne 'BEGIN{cnt=Hash.new(0)}
if $.==1 then 
    puts "cnt\t#{$_}"
else
    cnt[$_]+=1
end
END{ cnt.each{|k,v| puts "#{v}\t#{k}" } }
' file.tsv

Or awk:
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{print "cnt", $0; next}
!seen[$0]++ {order[++count] = $0}
END { 
    for (i=1; i<=count; i++) 
        print seen[order[i]], order[i] 
}' file.tsv

Or a two pass awk (for massive files with lots of duplicates):
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{if (NR==1) print "cnt",$0; next}
FNR==NR{cnt[$0]++; next}
!seen[$0]++{print cnt[$0], $0}
' file.tsv file.tsv

Those three all prints:
# ordered by when line first encountered - not by count.
cnt ASV Genus_Species   Taxid
5   cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum    amygdalinum 82755
2   46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia   solbrigii   460333
1   46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Marticorenia    foliosa 1910960
1   46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Leucheria   candidissima    1911693
1   46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Oxyphyllum  ulicinum    540062 


I posted my answer before looking at yours and then noticed we came up with similar but slightly different awk scripts. I found the differences interesting so I wrote a little blurb about that at the end of my answer. If you wouldn't mind taking a look to see if you agree with my comparison I'd appreciate it as I could easily be missing something.

As others have already mentioned, uniq works on groups of contiguous duplicates, not duplicates across the whole of the input.
Using any awk with a 2-pass approach:
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {
        cnt[$0]++
        next
    }
    $0 in cnt {
        print cnt[$0], $0
        delete cnt[$0]
    }
' file file
1 ASV Genus_Species   Taxid
5 cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
2 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia solbrigii 460333
1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Marticorenia foliosa    1910960
1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Leucheria candidissima  1911693
1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Oxyphyllum ulicinum 540062

or 1-pass but storing the input in memory:
$ awk '
    {
        cnt[$0]++
        ordr[NR] = $0
    }
    END {
        for ( i=1; i<=NR; i++ ) {
            rec = ordr[i]
            if ( rec in cnt ) {
                print cnt[rec], rec
                delete cnt[rec]
            }
        }
    }
' file
1 ASV Genus_Species   Taxid
5 cb692dc35226a27b1dc4709405077606    Gymnanthemum amygdalinum    82755
2 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Moscharia solbrigii 460333
1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Marticorenia foliosa    1910960
1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Leucheria candidissima  1911693
1 46c5e68b0c1230a4305382e0ddf34c5d    Oxyphyllum ulicinum 540062

I see that @dawg has similar scripts in their answer and I think the differences are interesting and subtle enough to be discussed. Here are @dawgs scripts written using the same style and variable names as I'm using above where applicable, to make the similarities and differences most obvious, and with a tweak where I think it's useful (IMO we should not use an array named seen[] to store and use/print counts, just to test for it's index having previously been seen or not):
Ed 1-pass:
awk '
    {
        cnt[$0]++
        ordr[NR] = $0
    }
    END {
        for ( i=1; i<=NR; i++ ) {
            rec = ordr[i]
            if ( rec in cnt ) {
                print cnt[rec], rec
                delete cnt[rec]
            }
        }
    }
' file

dawg 1-pass:
awk '
    !cnt[$0]++ {
        ordr[++numRecs] = $0
    }
    END { 
        for ( i=1; i<=numRecs; i++) {
            rec = ordr[i]
            print cnt[rec], rec
        }
    }
' file

Comparison: dawg is only storing the order for each unique $0 and only looping through the number of unique records whereas I'm storing the $0 for every line and looping through every line then deleting non-unique records. They are doing 1 extra increment and comparison than I am while loading the arrays but that's probably negligible overhead. Given that, dawg's script will use less memory and probably be more efficient than my script and so is the better approach.
Ed 2-pass:
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        cnt[$0]++
        next
    }
    $0 in cnt {
        print cnt[$0], $0
        delete cnt[$0]
    }
' file file

dawg 2-pass:
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        cnt[$0]++
        next
    }
    !seen[$0]++ {
        print cnt[$0], $0
    }
' file file

Comparison: we both store the record counts the same way on the first pass, but on the second pass dawg is creating an array seen[] of all of the unique records from the input so they will essentially have 2 copies of the input stored in memory (which means dawgs 2-pass script isn't actually using any less memory than their 1-pass script) where my approach only has 1 copy of the input stored in memory. dawg is doing a hash lookup plus arithmetic while I'm doing a hash lookup plus a deletion - in terms of execution speed it's probably not different enough either way to matter. Especially since we'd adopt this 2-pass approach if the input could be huge to avoid memory issues, otherwise we'd use the 1-pass approach, my approach is better as it's using half the memory of both 1-pass scripts and dawgs 2-pass script.

Totally agree with your analysis. One unknown however: I do know if g?awk does string interning. I think likely not since strings seem to be mutable. For languages that do do interning (Ruby, Rust, Python, Swift -- most newer ones), the additional overhead memory wise is negligible since the duplicate keys would refer to the same interned string.

@dawg good point. I was going to say that the gawk developers are pretty smart so they probably do do that (idk about the providers of any other awk variants) but then your point about the strings having to be immutable means that, in my opinion, they almost certainly do NOT do that in this case since the strings are mutable.

A decorate-sort-undecorate approach that doesn't store a lookup table
(so should work with files that don't fit in memory - sort uses temp files for large input):
awk '{print NR"\t"$0}' input.csv |
sort -k2 -k1n,1 |
uniq -c -f1 |
sort -k2n,2 |
sed 's/[0-9]*\t//'


prepend line numbers
sort ignoring the line number, then reorder identical lines by the line number
count the duplicates, ignoring the line number
re-sort to original line order
strip the line numbers


I am a sucker DSU algorithms...
